# Reverse proxy using Nginx to wordpress app hosted using nginx

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I'm trying to use nginx as reverse proxy(**Server A**) to my wordpress server(**Server B**) hosted using nginx. I am trying to setup my url in a sub-directory format, like *example.com/blog*

It kinda works but with some issues.

1. **Server A** has a LetsEncrypt SSL cert so it forces `https` on all routes. This is a problem because my wordpress app is loading .js & .css files on `http`.
2. After successful login, instead of redirecting to *example.com/blog/wp-admin*, it goes to *example.com/wp-admin*

My **Server A** nginx conf file with the appropriate location block,

```
location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://ip-address-for-server-b;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

My **Server B** nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }

    location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
         expires max;
         log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Also in my `wp-config.php`, I added these lines

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/blog' );
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `$uri/` element from the middle of your `try_files` statement?

Comment: That has fixed my Issue #2, where on login, it would redirect me to the wrong url. However the SSL issue is still there

Comment: If the `css` & `js` files belong to WP, they should be prefixed by WP_SITEURL. Which `css` & `js` files are using `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: @RichardSmith Seems like it's jquery, and some theme files. I added an image in the question.

Comment: You mention `wp-config.html`, do you mean `wp-config.php`? And you mention `#define(...);`, do you mean `define(...);` without the leading `#`?

Comment: Yes I did mean wp-config.php and yes the actual config does not have the `#`, I'll correct the details

Comment: `rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /$1 break;` would not pass "blog" sub-directory (to server B) that is needed for proper functioning of WordPress at example.com/blog . The second server isn't listening on port 443 that conflicts with the line `define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/blog' );`.